# Python (in range with random sum, max number and printing out in order)

Tags: python

Hello i need help how can i make a python program that sums random numbers in range, prints out the max number in range(prints out 10) and prints out the numbers in range in order(from 1-10). I only got the first part working the random sum in range, but it only works without the code for the last two.
All help would be appriciated

This is what i made so far:

```
from random import random
sum=0
for x in range(1,11):
    sum = sum + random()
print("the sum is ",sum)

else:
    maxNumber=0
    for x in range(1,11):
        maxNumber=maxNumber+11
        print("The max number in range is",maxNumber)
        print("Printing out in order",x)
```

Comment: What do mean by  *max number* in range? Isn't it just `10` for `range(1, 11)`?

Comment: Some questions to you (1)You want 11 random numbers and these numbers need to be in the range 1-11? Or you want to add 10 random numbers that can be anything? (2) you want to print the highest number, but you don't seem to store the numbers in a list or other data structure, you won't be able to find this information without it.

Comment: i mean the biggest number that is in the range

Comment: DJanssens -we have 1-11 numbers they arent random just they are summed randomly from 1-11 and yes they have to be in range

Comment: @Invader then why use the `random()` function of the random module? the first for loop currently will sum up 10 random numbers (which are in range `[0,1)`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting the "specifications" for this code as follows:

- Generate ten random numbers between 1 and 10, inclusive (i.e. 1 <= x <= 10)
- Find the sum of the numbers and report it
- Find the largest of the numbers and report it
- Print the numbers generated, in order from smallest to largest

I can't be certain that this is what you wanted, but the following Python 3.5 code performs these tasks: (I tested it)

```
import random

number_list = []
total = 0

for i in range(10):
    temp_number = random.randint(1, 10)
    total = total + temp_number
    number_list.append(temp_number)

print('The sum of the ten numbers is: ', total)

number_list.sort()

print('The largest number generated was: ', number_list[9])

print('The numbers generated were:')
for i in range(10):
    print(number_list[i])
```

Comment: you didnt get it right, i got myself the first part right. i only need the last to things. The second is the max number in range which has to print out 10, and then the 3 is it has to print out all number in range in order from 1-10

Comment: @Invader Please add this information to your question along with examples.

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not entirely clear what you want the code to do. If you could write a very clear explanation of what you wanted, it would be easier to help.